Dynamically change color of vega-lite area plot based on result of linear regression
We have time series data with an overlay of the linear regression to indicate the trend

Now we would like to color it red if the trend is declining as shown here

See the example
We have tried various ways with parameters but did not manage to have the color dependent on the trend. Our approach was focused on getting the slope and check if it was positive or negative.

What do you want to colour - the regression line or the area mark?

We want to color the area

Here you go. I'll let you fix the gradient.


{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "slope",
      "expr": " (data('data_1')[1]['date']-data('data_1')[0]['date'])/(data('data_1')[1]['value']-data('data_1')[0]['value']) "
    },
    {
      "name": "red",
      "expr": "{gradient: 'linear', stops: [{offset: 0, color: 'red'}, {offset: 1, color: 'red'}]}"
    },
    {
      "name": "green",
      "expr": "{gradient: 'linear', stops: [{offset: 0, color: 'green'}, {offset: 1, color: 'green'}]}"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2023-03-31", "value": 80},
      {"date": "2023-06-30", "value": 78},
      {"date": "2023-09-31", "value": 81},
      {"date": "2023-12-31", "value": 75},
      {"date": "2024-03-31", "value": 72},
      {"date": "2024-06-30", "value": 75},
      {"date": "2024-09-31", "value": 70}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
        "strokeWidth": 2,
        "clip": true
      },
      "transform": [{"regression": "value", "on": "date"}]
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "clip": true,
        "line": {"color": {"expr": "slope>0?'red':'green'"}, "strokeWidth": 4},
        "color": {"expr": "slope>0?red:green"}
      }
    }
  ]
}


Awesome, thank you very much!

For those looking for a version with the gradient switching colors as well (and dynamic tooltip).
Here's what we ended up with

